# How to find which version of RazorEngine works with which .net framework?

Tags: razorengine

It am struggling to find out the simple information of which `RazorEngine` version works with which version of .net framework.

I am basically looking for the version that can work with `.net core 2.2`, but the dot net core version of Razor Engine (`RazorEngine.NetCore 3.1.0`) works only with `.net core 3.1` and `.net standard 2.0`

I searched everything here https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine but could not find the .net core 2.2 compatible version of RazorEngine

Can anybody help?